# Laravel 5.5 Localization and CKEditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I want to replace multiple textarea (Content En and Content Ru) by ckeditor, but they all have the same ID. How to do, because after loading one editor, it stops.

Form:

```
{!! Form::open([ 'route' => 'portfolio.store', 'files' => 'true']) !!}

        @foreach(config('translatable.locales') as $locale)
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="translation[{{$locale}}][title]"><strong>Title ({{$locale}})</strong></label>
                <input type="text" id="title"
                       name="translation[{{$locale}}][title]"
                       class="form-control"
                       value="{{ old('translation.'. $locale.'.title')  }}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="translation[{{$locale}}][content]"><strong>Content ({{$locale}})</strong></label>
                <textarea name="translation[{{$locale}}][content]"
                          id="content"
                          class="form-control"
                          cols="30"
                          rows="10">{{ old('translation.'. $locale.'.content') }}</textarea>
            </div>
        @endforeach

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="image"><strong>Image</strong></label>
                <input type="file" id="image" name="image" class="form-control-file">
            </div>
            <br>

            <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Add Portfolio">
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Script:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml2qH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can explain how it works from CKEditor point of view.

Please see: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#cfg-replaceClass and http://nightly.ckeditor.com/18-09-06-06-04/full/samples/old/replacebyclass.html.

CKEditor allwos replacing multiple textareas provided that they have one specific CSS class assigned (`ckeditor` by default). All you need to do is attach CKEditor script in header section of your HTML document and then add a bunch of `<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea>` elements. They should be auto-changed to editor.

Alternatively you can generate `textarea` elements with random `id's`, collect those `id's` and then run the `replace` method in a loop, using `id` from the iteration step.

Comment: No problem. If you find this solution as the correct one, please mark my post as accepted answer so that others could know.